# Choosing a random string in C# for WP7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, random

I am making a WP7 app that, when a user taps an image, randomly decides what they will get.

Right now, I have this code:

`string firstdoor = "";`

`string seconddoor = "";`

`string thirddoor = "";`

and

`string prize1 = "vacation to Hawaii with all expenses covered";`

`string prize2 = "used glue stick";`

`string prize3 = "pile of dog dung";`

`string prize3 = "vacation to Europe with all expenses covered";`

`string prize3 = "million dollars";`

`string prize3 = "blank CD";`

`string prize3 = "temporary tattoo";`

`string prize3 = "nickel";`

`string prize3 = "dime";`

and

What I want to do is randomly assign the `door`s to the `prize`s.

For instance, when the user taps the image, `dime` is assigned to `thirddoor`, `nickel` is assigned to firstdoor, and `million dollars` is assigned to `secondoor`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps that seem to make the most sense to me (not going to write all the code for you):

1. Put all prize strings in an array.
2. Generate three random numbers between 0 and the maximum number of prizes.
3. Assign each door the prize from the prize array with each of the random numbers.
4. ...
5. Profit!

**Edit**

Actually, here's a little bit of code to help out:

```
var randomGenerator = new Random();

string[] prizes = { "vacation to Hawaii with all expenses covered",
                    "used glue stick",
                    "pile of dog dung",
                    "vacation to Europe with all expenses covered" };

string firstDoor = prizes[randomGenerator.Next(prizes.Length)];
string secondDoor = prizes[randomGenerator.Next(prizes.Length)];
string thirdDoor = prizes[randomGenerator.Next(prizes.Length)];
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution crashes the app randomly. I don't have much programming experience, so I don't know why. VS 2010 says: System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=IndexOutOfRangeException
  StackTrace:
       at STGS.Play.image3_MouseEnter(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)

Comment: randomGenerator.Next(n) will generate numbers between 0 and n-1, hence in the sample above it can resolve to an index of -1. If you change to string firstDoor = prizes[randomGenerator.Next(prizes.Length)];   etc, it will work

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you don't want to repeat any of the prizes the solution is a little more complicated, but you can bring some Linq and a little trick with Random into play:

```
    var prizes = new string[] {
        "vacation to Hawaii with all expenses covered",
        "used glue stick",
        // etc
        "dime"            
    };

    var rand = new Random();

    var result = (from prize in prizes
                  orderby rand.NextDouble()
                  select prize).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton-This is **the** fastest time I have had a question answered in.

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure you accept whichever answer most fits your requirement - thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1):

Justin, your answer is fine but might result in 2 doors having the same prize. I believe this might be better:

```
string[] prizes = new string[]
        {
            "Prize 1",
            "Prize 2",
            "Prize 3",
            "Prize 4",
            "Prize 5"
        };

        Random r = new Random();
        var choices = prizes.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).Take(3).ToArray();

        string firstDoor = choices[0];
        string secondDoor = choices[1];
        string thirdDoor = choices[2];
```

Comment: StackOverflowTime is measured in milliseconds ;)